# Query for custom post types not working via AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type called 'award'. I'm on `archive-award.php` and I'm displaying a list of the 'award' posts. So far so good.

Now I want to pull the next posts via AJAX, at the click of a 'Load More' button. Here's the action I pass to the AJAX script:

```
function load_next_award_posts() { 

    $args = array(
        'paged' => 2, 
        'post_type' => 'award',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $next_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    if( $next_posts->have_posts() ) :   
        while( $next_posts->have_posts() ) : $next_posts->the_post(); 
            echo '<p>Hello</p>';
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();
    die(); 

}
```

Unfortunately, the query returns no results. If instead I change the `post_type` to the default `post` or `page`, it all works fine. So what's going on? Why isn't the query working with my custom post type?

Comment: can you add your ajax call action and ajax code to this.

Comment: @SunilDora My ajax call and code are fine, otherwise I wouldn't get results when changing the `post_type` to `post` or `page`. The problem only occurs when I query my custom post type, so it must be something related to that.

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/ Just go through this article, no need to take care of post type, it will perfectly do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="more_posts" href="#">Load More</a>
```

Your file.js

```
    var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>";
    var page = 1; // What page we are on.
    var ppp = 10; // Post per page

    $("#more_posts").on("click",function(){
        $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
        $.post(ajaxUrl, {
            action:"more_post_ajax",
            offset: (page * ppp) + 1,
            ppp: ppp
        }).success(function(posts){
            page++;
            $(".name_of_posts_class").append(posts);
            $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",false);
        });

   });

</script>
```

Functions.php

```
function more_post_ajax(){
    $offset = $_POST["offset"];
    $ppp = $_POST["ppp"];
    header("Content-Type: text/html");

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'award',
        'posts_per_page' => $ppp,
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) { $loop->the_post(); 
       the_content();
    }

    exit; 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_more_post_ajax', 'more_post_ajax');
```

Comment: Yes, add this script in your archive-award.php file

Comment: By default post_per_page = 10. Have you got 10 awards minimum ?